# SQL: Query Entire Database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am a complete beginner in SQL. I am using a program that queries a database, and then processes the results. The default query is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM data, 
     questions, 
     users 
where users.U_Id = data.Subj_Id 
  and data.Subj_Id between 1 and 10 
  and data.Q_Id = questions.Q_Id 
  and questions.Q_Id between 1 and 10 
order by Subj_Id;
```

I'd like it to query every `Subj_Id` and every `Q_Id`. I do not know how many there are of either, and different subjects have different numbers of questions. How should I alter the above query?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rewrite the above query like this.

```
select * 
from 
    data 
        inner join 
    users on users.U_Id = data.Subj_Id 
        inner join 
    questions on data.Q_Id = questions.Q_Id 
where data.Subj_Id between 1 and 10 
and questions.Q_Id between 1 and 10 
order by Subj_Id;
```

This makes it clearer by separating the joins between tables from the filters on the data. 
So to query the entire database, you just remove the `where` clause from the above...

```
select * 
from 
    data 
        inner join 
    users on users.U_Id = data.Subj_Id 
        inner join 
    questions on data.Q_Id = questions.Q_Id 
order by Subj_Id;
```

Comment: Got it! Thank you. What does `inner join` mean?